# Using Javascript in Acrobat what code would allow me to "Save as" found text?

Tags: javascript, automation, dom-events, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I work with pdfs on a daily basis that contain the text **OCA/<12 character text>**. I'm hoping to obtain Acrobat Javascript code that will copy the 12 character text that follows **OCA/** and "Save As" the found 12 character text + the word "MISC" (i.e. X--XXXXXXXXX MISC). I should mention the 12 characters always include the two hyphens in space 2 and 3 from the left (not sure if that matters) and OCA/ is never in the same area of the page however will always be found on the first page. I've learned from other forums that this possibly involves using the **getPageNthWord** method and **folder level javascript files** stored in the Acrobat JavaScript folder. **Your script is highly appreciated**. Thank you in advance. A visual is linked here:
[Example of text to be found / copied / save as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCZkZ.jpg)

Comment: Thank you K J. It is indeed a continuous block of text that would cut and paste as you wrote with no spaces, breaks, or wrapping. I appreciate your idea. Is there a chance you could offer code that may accomplish the method you suggest? My goal is to automate the task connecting the code to a menu button or Custom Action in Acrobat. Much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you K J. Although I don’t understand your reply I do appreciate the suggestions. This at least gives me some feedback. I may repost if I get a better idea from other pros. I’m not giving up on this, LOL. Thank you!

Comment: Please disregard. Thank you for your time. This is now posted elsewhere. Much appreciated.